# what Format is really need for Video Players?

Tags: html5

in all new video player plugins for word press there are some various field for various formats !!

like : FLV , Mp4 , OGV , Webm , Mp4 for mobile

as my Web host have limit of Size i really confused and not know which of these formats is important for play in most browser

for example for a video clip with size 40MB in Flv , i will have 180 MB in create 3 format ( Mp4 , flv , Ogv )

is there any standard format that support all browser and html5 video player ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one format that works on all browsers, for example, Firefox won't play MP4 files due to FF not having the license to use the MP4 codec.

You definitely need OGV and MP4 versions, the others will depend on other browsers and choice, it's better to upload all versions to give you piece of mind the video will work for everyone.

Comment: thanks

what about FLV ?? cause seems Stream Video player plugin recommended to use this as main or default

Comment: By default safari does not have flash support so flv will not work on iPhone/iPads or on Mac.